# NDSolve with varying PrecisionGoal and WorkingPrecision

Tags: differential-equations, arbitrary-precision

Sometimes we need higher numerical precision to deal with large number cancellation in an equation. But if this cancellation happens only in a small (and known) parameter space, would it be possible to only use high precision calculation in that small part of the parameter space? For example, something like

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> If[x < 5, $MachinePrecision, 50], 
      PrecisionGoal -> If[x < 5, $MachinePrecision, 50]]
```

This code doesn't work, because *Mathematica* doesn't relate the `x` in the two `If` expressions to the `x` in the ODE. Is there any way to make the above idea work?

Comment: Note that `$MachinePrecision` is different from `MachinePrecision`.  `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` uses arbitrary precision with `$MachinePrecision` digits of precision, which may be what you wanted.  One can use `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision`, which is the default, for machine precision calculation, when desired.

Answer (score 3):

No direct way I'm aware of to do this: as far as I know, when the initial `NDSolve` is evaluated, those options a plugged into an internal slot and can't be tinkered.

However, perhaps something like this would serve your purpose:

```
low = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision, 
       PrecisionGoal -> $MachinePrecision];

high = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 5, 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 50];

myinterpolating[x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{(y /. First@low)[x], x < 5}, {(y /. First@high)[x], 
     x >= 5}}];

Column[{x = myinterpolating[2], Precision[x], y = myinterpolating[10],
   Precision[y]}]

(*

0.528357862862939 
15.3332
0.06434904783198493788519509130059592424856983961826
49.0072

*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One thing I was not sure is, for `high`, because there is `y[0] == 1` condition, does `NDSolve` really start from x=5, or it has to start from x=0 and thus has the same performance as starting to integrate using high performance from the beginning?

Comment: @YiWang: Good question - I can't answer definitively (code-speak for "beats me"). I suppose some timings are in order...and I'm sure experts in the function will chime in. Edit: just did some quick timings, it takes *longer* with a higher lower bound - puzzling, so I'm not sure if my idea will be of any use to you.

Comment: I think this doesn't really do what you expect and the OP intended: if you give a start value for `x=0` but ask `NDSolve` to solve for `x=5` to `x=30` in the second call it will actually solve from `x=0` with high precision but only store the results from 5 to 30 in the result. If you want to only solve with low precision you should instead give the lower precision endpoint result as starting value for the second call, something like: `y[0] == SetPrecision[(y /. First@low)[5], 50]`...

Comment: @AlbertRetey: I thought of that but didn't try it - working on other stuff. Still puzzling that it takes more time with a higher lower bound than just doing the whole range. Perhaps combining that code with mine will be useful to OP, I'll tinker with the idea when time permits.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that the difference might be that with a higher lower bound NDSolve will try to make an exact match in the x-steps for that value which might result in a slightly different discretization. You can see similar effects with e.g. `NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5, 30}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 50]`. See e.g. this answer about the undocumented feature I used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/452/169) for the `x` range specification...